# Fastest way to check if values in object array are different

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got two arrays: `model` and `workModel` and each of them contains a `values` array. Before sending `POST` request, I want to check which values have been updated.

```js
dataToUpdate(workModel: Data[]) {
        let data: Data[];
        this.model.forEach(m => {
            m.values.forEach(val => {
                
                workModel.forEach(wm => {
                    wm.values.forEach(wval => {
                        if (val.colId != wval.colId) {
                            data.push(wm);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });

        return data;
    }
```

is there a faster way to do that?

example of the array:

```js
 "model": [
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "colId": 1,
              "value": 7086083333.333333
            },
            {
              "colId": 2,
              "value": null
            },
            {
              "colId": 3,
              "value": null
            }
          ],
          "rowId": 0,
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "colId": 1,
              "value": null
            },
          ],
          "rowId": 1,
          "rowHeader": ""
        },
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "colId": 1,
              "value": null
            },
            {
              "colId": 2,
              "value": null
            },
            {
              "colId": 3,
              "value": null
            }
          ],
          "rowId": 2,
          "rowHeader": ""
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what your data looks like? It's hard to give a good answer if we have to reverse engineer the shape of the objects from nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions about your data you could do something like this. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Basically flatMap both arrays into a single array of values then filter over them and dedupe it.

```
function dataToUpdate(workModel: Data[]) {
    return workModel
        .flatMap((wm) => wm.values)
        .concat(this.model.flatMap((m) => m.values))
        .filter((val, i, arr) => {
            return arr.findIndex((v) => v.colId === val.colId) === i;
        });
}
```

You can also do something like this which is faster for extremely big arrays.

```
function dataToUpdate(workModel: Data[]) {
    const flat = workModel.flatMap((wm) => wm.values).concat(this.model.flatMap((m) => m.values));
    const uniqIds = new Set(flat.map((col) => col.colId));
    return flat.filter(uniqIds.delete)
}
```

Comment: This is going to run in `O(n^2)` time - I doubt it's much faster than what OP has.

Comment: noob question, is map and flatMap same, flatMap gives error 'Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'any[]'.ts(2339)
' and I've added array example

Comment: try adding "esnext" to your lib array in tsconfig let me know if this helps (also add a polyfill for older browsers if you're doing this on the web). You can read more about flatMap here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: @user122222 TS might not be configured to recognise new JS features. [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is quite new - post ES6. It's a `map` operation coupled with "flattening the result, e.g., you have `[1, 2, 3]` and `.map(x => [x*2])` would give you `[[2], [4], [6]]` while `.flatMap(x => [x*2])` will keep the array at one level - `[2, 4, 6]`.

Comment: No problem, some slightly related advice for the future to avoid `for` loops in general is that `all` Array based algorithms can actually be solved using only Array.prototype.reduce and flatMap, concat, map, filter are just syntax sugar for using reduce easier.